# Ruby If and Unless conditional explanation

Tags: ruby, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to ask for a little explanation about if and unless, I know the two of this is an opposite of each other. All of this time I have used both without no problem until now I find something weird. Let's check my code :

```
ausysdir = AUDIO_SYSTEM_FOLDER_NAME 

Dir.mkdir(ausysdir) if ausysdir != "" && !File.directory?(ausysdir)     # Number 1 
Dir.mkdir(ausysdir) unless ausysdir == "" && File.directory?(ausysdir)  # Number 2
```

Now in the directory I work the folder **ausdyr** is already exist. 
But from the code above the the number one conditional which is **if** not return an error(this is what I expected, so great), But not with number 2 conditional which is **unless**, when I think that **if** and unless is an opposite, then my syntax above should be correct, am I right? Or my syntax is wrong? Or **Unless** have a different behaviour? Or do I missed something here?

Thank you very much.

EDIT : When I mean error, is an exception because the file is already exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unless expr` is the same as `if !expr`. But `!(a && b)` is not `!a && !b` as you seem to think, it is actually `!a || !b` (this is one of De Morgan's laws BTW). So your `if` and `unless` statements are not at all equivalent.

Build the truth table if you don't believe me. Then study some Propositional Calculus (which every programmer should be familiar with) if you don't believe your truth table.

If your `if` works then you're `unless` would be:

```
unless ausysdir == "" || File.directory?(ausysdir)
```

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR Don't use `unless` with more than one condition. Most people have to think too hard to understand it, and then have about a 50/50 chance of getting it right.

---

Here is a test of two booleans using `if`/`unless` and `&&`/`or`:

```
def test(first, second)
  puts "#{first}, #{second}"
  puts "  ...passes if #{first} && #{second}" if first && second
  puts "  ...passes unless #{first} && #{second}" unless first && second
  puts "  ...passes if #{first} || #{second}" if first || second
  puts "  ...passes unless #{first} || #{second}" unless first || second
end

test(true, true)
test(true, false)
test(false, true)
test(false, false)
```

The results:

```
true && true
  ...passes if true && true
  ...passes if true || true
true && false
  ...passes unless true && false
  ...passes if true || false
false && true
  ...passes unless false && true
  ...passes if false || true
false && false
  ...passes unless false && false
  ...passes unless false || false
```

Your first condition boils down to `if false && false`, according to the `false, false` results above, `if false && false` **doesn't** pass. *Reaction: Pretty straightforward and easy to see.*

Your second condition boils down to `unless false && true`, according to the `false, true` results above,  `unless false && true` **does** pass. *Reaction: That seems like it possibly might make sense if I think about it some more.*

Comment: You're right, I need to think twice for unless conditional(even give me headache), I think I should stick with if =) 
I just playing around and surprised about the result of my code above, but it gave me a lot more knowledge about this matter.
Thank you very much.

Comment: @LuminaChen, It is considered good practice in perl(by some) to NEVER use unless.  I follow that rule in ruby, too.  In most cases, `unless` also gives me a headache. :(